# markdown generated book does not show book cover when opens in e-reader

Tags: r-markdown

I'm using R markdown to write a book and I have added a book cover image in the file index.Rmd as follows:

```
knitr::include_graphics('bookCover.png', dpi = NA)
```

The book renders correctly, but when I when I open it with an e-reader (e.g., Mac Books) it does not show the book cover. It shows a generic cover with the title and author. The cover image appears on page 4.

Any suggestion on how to make the book cover show first when I open it in the e-reader?

I have been searching the web and read different markdown but I was not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively simple hack to my problem. Download Calibre from https://calibre-ebook.com/. Start Calibre and using "add books" open the _main.epub. Select "edit metadata individually" and pronto you have an option to upload an image that becomes the cover of your book. Save the update ePub and opening with the eReader you can see the cover of your book.